# Practicalities of the "graze until they become defected" strategy

Tags: animals, korban, agriculture, maseches-zevachim

[Mishnayot Zevachim 8:1-3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Zevachim.8.1-3) repeatedly prescribe the strategy of "יִרְעוּ עַד שֶׁיִּסְתָּאֲבוּ" - "they graze until they become defected" for dealing with animals that are stuck in situations of doubt with respect to whether they should be offered as *korbanot*. The idea is that the doubtful animal is left to graze until it develops a defect that invalidates it for offering. When that happens, it's legal to sell the animal to the general meat market and then use the proceeds to purchase whatever *korban* it may have been committed to.

I'm wondering how this strategy works, in practice.

- Are animals destined to be *korbanot* kept in safer conditions than general-market animals, while those in this יע"ש situation are kept in regular conditions?

Or:

- Are animals destined to be *korbanot* kept in the same conditions as general-market animals, while those in this יע"ש situation are kept in worse conditions?

Or:

- Are all animals kept in the same conditions, and we assume it's just a matter of time until they develop a defect?

In any case:

- Is there a standard period of time, under יע"ש conditions, within which it's expected that an animal will develop a defect, or is there a wide distribution for this duration, such that many such animals pasture for the rest of their lives?

Comment: In Europe they use to keep them in the cemetery IINM

Comment: The Bostoner Rebbe, זצ''ל, had a story about this in his book, _And the Angels Laughed_.  A farmer had a _bechor_ in his flock of cattle.  He allowed it to graze normally, and wildly, until the inspector (from USDA?) stapled a label to its ear, which made it a _ba'al mum_.  In this case, it waited for the inspector's second visit (a year later), as the staple the first year hadn't properly injured the calf.

Comment: BTW: Not all "יִרְעוּ עַד שֶׁיִּסְתָּאֲבוּ" are "sold to purchase a Korban".  A Bechor (firstborn) is "יִרְעוּ עַד שֶׁיִּסְתָּאֲבוּ"  and then can be eaten by its owner.

Comment: My wife's great-grandfather  Rav Avrohom Mordechai Cohen (1868-1958) was given a calf as a Bechor in Kovno. He kept it chained to a tree as it grew into a huge bull. Once a year a Rov would approach it fearfully to check it for blemishes. One (un)happy night a wolf attacked and ate it.

Comment: My answer should be accepted, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I would deduct that your first guess is the correct one .

For the *korbanot* conditions, it's common sense.

For the **יע"ש**:

Mishna Bechorot p5

> מתני' מעשה בזכר של רחלים זקן ושערו מדולדל וראהו קסטור אחד ואמר מה טיבו
>   של זה אמרו לו בכור הוא ואינו נשחט אלא א"כ היה בו מום נטל פיגום וצרם
>   אזנו ובא מעשה לפני חכמים והתירו ואחר שהתירו הלך וצירם באזני בכורות
>   אחרים ואסרו ...זה הכלל כל שהוא לדעתו אסור
>   שלא לדעתו מותר:

"A deed of old *bechor* sheep... A Rome saw it and asked "Why it's in this condition (old age)?", He was answered "It's *bechor*, and not to be slain until defected". He took a rod and injured his ear. The sages allowed to use the meat. When the Rome did it again they forbid it...That's the rule - If it's unknowingly, it's allowed, but if knowingly, it's forbid"

So if the *bechor* reached old age I guess that it wasn't really poorly treated.

It also answers your last question.